# Join two ordered sequences efficiently in C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, enumeration

Presume these two ordered sequences:

```
var outer = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e' };
var inner = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd' };
```

Knowing that elements from both sequences are ordered, how can they be inner-joined more efficiently than with `Enumerable.Join` to produce the following sequence of tuples?

```
{ 'a', 'a' }
{ 'b', 'b' }
{ 'b', 'b' }
{ 'c', 'c' }
{ 'c', 'c' }
{ 'd', 'd' }
{ 'd', 'd' }
{ 'd', 'd' }
{ 'd', 'd' }
```

Notice that, unlike with `Enumerable.Intersect` that produces only distinct elements from both sequences, the output sequence here returns tuples that represent every combination of elements from a one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many relationship.

The semantics are much the same as `INNER JOIN` in SQL Server. But, more specifically, I'm looking for a C# implementation with the performance characteristics of the [merge join](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/08/03/merge-join/) algorithm (`INNER MERGE JOIN`) that returns an `IEnumerable` with deferred execution.

The required method signature might look something like this:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> MergeJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, 
    IEnumerable<TInner> inner, 
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, 
    Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, 
    Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
```

Comment: Is something stopping you from implementing this yourself? You've even linked to some pseudo-code. Is the question here "write the code for me"?

Comment: I will post my answer soon.

Comment: Can you change `outer, inner` type to `IList`, for example?

Comment: No, you have to assume there's no upfront knowledge about the number of elements in either sequence nor do you have the ability to access any arbitrary element by its ordinal position or in some sparse fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MoreEnumerable.OrderedMerge` from **MoreLinq** library does the job if both sequences are sorted.

https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ

```
using MoreLinq;

IEnumerable<char> result = outer.OrderedMerge(innner);
```

Efficiency is good, compared to inner join.
When N and M are the length of each sequence,
Inner join makes a cartesian product so time is proportional to NxM
OrderedMerge traverse each collection once so time is proportional to N+M

If the sequences are not sorted, the standard **Linq** `Enumerable.OrderBy` will do the job.

There are also some overloads:

```
// to provide a custom comparison criteria
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderedMerge<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, IComparer<T> comparer);

// to provide the key for comparisons
IEnumerable<T> OrderedMerge<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T, TKey> keySelector);

// + other overloads to select element to be merged when first element is less than second, 
// when second element is less than first 
// when first and second element are equal
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any existing `Enumerable` extension method that achieves this and no one should ever have to spend more time than I did to come up with this.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MergeJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> inner, Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    if (outer == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outer));

    if (inner == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inner));

    if (outerKeySelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outerKeySelector));

    if (innerKeySelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerKeySelector));

    if (resultSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));

    return MergeJoinIterator(outer, inner, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, resultSelector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> MergeJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> inner, Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    if (outer == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outer));

    if (inner == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inner));

    if (outerKeySelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outerKeySelector));

    if (innerKeySelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(innerKeySelector));

    if (resultSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));

    if (comparer == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));

    return MergeJoinIterator(outer, inner, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, resultSelector, comparer);
}

private static IEnumerable<TResult> MergeJoinIterator<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> inner, Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    IEnumerator<TOuter> outerEnumerator = outer.GetEnumerator();

    if (!outerEnumerator.MoveNext())
        yield break;

    IEnumerator<TInner> innerEnumerator = inner.GetEnumerator();

    if (!innerEnumerator.MoveNext())
        yield break;

    TOuter outerElement = outerEnumerator.Current;
    TKey outerKey = outerKeySelector(outerElement);

    TInner innerElement = innerEnumerator.Current;
    TKey innerKey = innerKeySelector(innerElement);

    int comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKey);

    while (true)
    {
        if (comp < 0)
        {
            if (!innerEnumerator.MoveNext())
                break;

            innerElement = innerEnumerator.Current;
            innerKey = innerKeySelector(innerElement);
            comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKey);
            continue;
        }

        if (comp > 0)
        {
            if (!outerEnumerator.MoveNext())
                break;

            outerElement = outerEnumerator.Current;
            outerKey = outerKeySelector(outerElement);
            comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKey);
            continue;
        }

        yield return resultSelector(outerElement, innerElement);

        if (!outerEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!innerEnumerator.MoveNext())
                    break;

                innerElement = innerEnumerator.Current;
                innerKey = innerKeySelector(innerElement);
                comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKey);

                if (comp != 0)
                    break;

                yield return resultSelector(outerElement, innerElement);
            }

            break;
        }

        if (!innerEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                outerElement = outerEnumerator.Current;
                outerKey = outerKeySelector(outerElement);
                comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKey);

                if (comp != 0)
                    break;

                yield return resultSelector(outerElement, innerElement);

                if (!outerEnumerator.MoveNext())
                    break;
            }

            break;
        }

        TOuter outerElementNext = outerEnumerator.Current;
        TKey outerKeyNext = outerKeySelector(outerElementNext);

        TInner innerElementNext = innerEnumerator.Current;
        TKey innerKeyNext = innerKeySelector(innerElementNext);

        comp = comparer.Compare(outerKeyNext, outerKey);
        bool stop = false;

        if (comp != 0)
        {
            comp = comparer.Compare(innerKeyNext, innerKey);

            if (comp == 0)
            {
                yield return resultSelector(outerElement, innerElementNext);

                while (true)
                {
                    if (!innerEnumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        stop = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    innerElementNext = innerEnumerator.Current;
                    innerKeyNext = innerKeySelector(innerElementNext);
                    comp = comparer.Compare(innerKeyNext, outerKey);

                    if (comp != 0)
                        break;

                    yield return resultSelector(outerElement, innerElementNext);
                }

                if (stop)
                    break;
            }

            outerElement = outerElementNext;
            outerKey = outerKeyNext;
            innerElement = innerElementNext;
            innerKey = innerKeyNext;
            comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKey);
            continue;
        }

        comp = comparer.Compare(innerKeyNext, innerKey);

        if (comp != 0)
        {
            yield return resultSelector(outerElementNext, innerElement);

            while (true)
            {
                if (!outerEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }

                outerElementNext = outerEnumerator.Current;
                outerKeyNext = outerKeySelector(outerElementNext);
                comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKeyNext);

                if (comp != 0)
                    break;

                yield return resultSelector(outerElementNext, innerElement);
            }

            if (stop)
                break;

            outerElement = outerElementNext;
            outerKey = outerKeyNext;
            innerElement = innerElementNext;
            innerKey = innerKeyNext;
            comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKey);
            continue;
        }

        yield return resultSelector(outerElement, innerElementNext);
        var innerRest = new List<TInner>();

        TInner innerElementFollowing = default(TInner);
        TKey innerKeyFollowing = default(TKey);

        while (true)
        {
            if (!innerEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                stop = true;
                break;
            }

            innerElementFollowing = innerEnumerator.Current;
            innerKeyFollowing = innerKeySelector(innerElementFollowing);
            comp = comparer.Compare(innerKeyFollowing, outerKey);

            if (comp != 0)
                break;

            yield return resultSelector(outerElement, innerElementFollowing);
            innerRest.Add(innerElementFollowing);
        }

        yield return resultSelector(outerElementNext, innerElement);
        yield return resultSelector(outerElementNext, innerElementNext);

        for (int i = 0; i < innerRest.Count; i++)
            yield return resultSelector(outerElementNext, innerRest[i]);

        while (true)
        {
            if (!outerEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                stop = true;
                break;
            }

            outerElementNext = outerEnumerator.Current;
            outerKeyNext = outerKeySelector(outerElementNext);
            comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKeyNext);

            if (comp != 0)
                break;

            yield return resultSelector(outerElementNext, innerElement);
            yield return resultSelector(outerElementNext, innerElementNext);

            for (int i = 0; i < innerRest.Count; i++)
                yield return resultSelector(outerElementNext, innerRest[i]);
        }

        if (stop)
            break;

        outerElement = outerElementNext;
        outerKey = outerKeyNext;
        innerElement = innerElementFollowing;
        innerKey = innerKeyFollowing;
        comp = comparer.Compare(innerKey, outerKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you disclose your tests? I simply tried with the following: `var r = new Random(100);var outer = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).Select(x => r.Next(500)).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();var inner = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).Select(x => r.Next(500)).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();/*Stopwatch...;*/var res = MergeJoin(outer, inner, o => o, i => i, (o, i) => new { o, i }).ToList();` and `Join` was faster than both, your and my implementation. So I'm interested under which circumstances yours actually performs better

Comment: Running your test on my side, `Enumerable.Join` does appear to out perform `MergeJoin`.  Interestingly, when bumping up the maximum values for random numbers to 10000 (averaging 10 duplicates in every sequence), `MergeJoin` starts performing better. I guess this technique really shines when sequences don't hold excessive duplicates or when you when you might decide to escape early.

Comment: In a best case scenario, with a one-to-one relationship, `MergeJoin` is about 3.5 times quicker joining sequences of 1 million unique elements each.

Comment: More so, `Enumerable.Join` really begins to work hard when further increasing the number of unique elements in the inner sequence.

Comment: Seems your approach excells for more unique elements (really impressive), while for more duplicate elements your performance is comparable to join but not really better (at least for the few tests I did run).

Comment: My findings are similar to yours. And both seem equally good at dieing with an OutOfMemoryException for big enough, entirely duplicated, sequences :)